# wcfsvchost and VS 2012 express

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express

I'm trying to get started on WCF using VS Studio 2012 Express for Web 32bit on a Win7 x64 machine.  THe debugger is supposed to launch wcfsvchost.exe to test out my WCF service, but this file is nowhere on my machine.  I have tried re-installing VS 2012 and updating to Update 3 but still no sign of this exe on my machine.  I cannot find any info on the net indicating this utility is not provided with the Express version of VS.

Any help on what I am missing greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set few things in the WCF  project Properties in order to open the WCFService test Client.

```
Project-> Right Click -> Debug -> Chooose Start Project radio Button.
```

and set the following parameter in commandlike argument.

```
/client:"WcfTestClient.exe"
```

Comment: I know about setting the /client parameter.  But I assume that is a command line parameter for running wcfsvchost.exe which won't happen if the wcfsvchost.exe file is nowhere on my machine.